# Исправление ошибки, допущенной в предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, типы-ошибок

**Мать с дочерью, сдающей на следующий день вступительные экзамены, не могла уснуть от волнения.**
Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 1):

Мать и дочь, которой на следующий день предстояли вступительные экзамены, не могл**и** уснуть от волнения.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, почему "сдающей на следующий день" заменено на " которой на следующий день предстояли"?

Comment: Возможно, в этом и нет ошибки, но считается, что _причастий будущего времени_ в русском нет, а смысл сказанного именно такой. На всякий случай перефразировал.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматическая ошибка здесь одна - сказуемое относится к двум деятелям, мать с дочерью - подлежащее, следовательно,сказуемое во множественном числе:
*Мать с дочерью, сдающей на следующий день вступительные экзамены, не могл**и** уснуть от волнения.*

Остальное - корявость стиля.

Comment: @ Людмила, а почему причастие в ед.ч. у вас?

Comment: Так ведь причастный оборот относится только к дочери, она сдаёт экзамен, а не мать.

Comment: я понимаю. Но ведь подлежащее мать с дочерью.  Не только дочь. В любом случае предложение следует исправить. Вариант Александра хороший.

Comment: @Людмила. А сочетание причастия наст. вр. несов. вида с указанием на буд. время  (сдающая на следующий день) — не ошибка?

Comment: Нет, это не ошибка,это троп,  можно же сказать "я завтра сдаю экзамен" - глагол настоящего времени в значении будущего. Данное задание предполагает нахождение ошибки , связанной с нарушением связи между подлежащим и сказуемым, её и следует исправлять

Answer (score 0):

Кто не мог устунуть? Мать? Тогда так (как вариант):

**Дочери на следующий день предстояло сдавать вступительные экзамены, и мать не могла уснуть от волнения.**

**Мать не могла уснуть от волнения, потому что ее дочери на следующий день предстояло сдавать вступительные экзамены.**

Примечания

- Неужели в один день сдают несколько экзаменов?
- Порядок слов (на следующий день предстояло сдавать вступительные экзамены) изменен для благозвучности.